# Mysterious padding/margin between <li> and <ul> elements

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I was building a menu when I noticed this gap between `<li>` and `<ul>`. Even setting margin and padding to 0 doesn't solve it, I have no idea of where it comes from.

I isolated the issue in the example below.

Code rendered: http://gyazo.com/a8051a862c08c4dce4ce0b44ab4b271b

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <style>
      div#container{
         display: inline-block;
         border: 5px solid #00ff00;
      } 

      ul{
         list-style: none;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
         border: 5px solid #0000ff;

      }

      li{
         display: inline-block;
         border: 5px solid #ff0000;
         width: 30px;
         height: 30px;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
      }
   </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
   <ul >
      <li></li><li></li>
   </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Funny thing is that if I write anything inside the `<li>` elements, the gap disappears. Can somebody explain to me what is going on and how I can remove this gap?

Answer (score 1):

What nathan suggested is a solution, here is another, without using `inline-block` display format as it can create problems at times with `<ul>` without a content (as in your case).....this demo is using `floats` and has no-content

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/ue542/)

**CSS**

```
  li{
      display: block;
      border: 5px solid #CCC;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      float:left; //added this
     }
.clearfix   {clear:both;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <ul ><li></li><li></li>
    <div class="clearfix"   ></div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add another answer to the one answered earlier which is totally different from the one already answered.

You need to use `vertical-align` property if you are using an `inline-block` display for it to work.

**For Instance,**

**The CSS change:**

```
 div#container{
         display: inline-block;
         border: 5px solid #00ff00;
         vertical-align:top;
      } 


      li{
         display: inline-block;
         border: 5px solid #ff0000;
         width: 30px;
         height: 30px;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
         vertical-align:top;
      }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qV8kv/1/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: assuming that we are provided the `working answers` and kikou ain't responding....he is not in mood to participate, he'll just copy the correct answer to his use, that's it ! ;)

Comment: @Mayank - in fairness, kikou does ask for an explanation of what's going on - i.e. how the inline-blocks are interacting with the baseline of their containing line box - not just how to remove the space. None of the answers here provides such an explanation.

Comment: @Alohci :  WADR sir....SO is about explanations too and not just answers, i understand this, but OP vanished altogether without any response, i comment was in lieu to that!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `&nbsp;` to resolve your issue.

**For Instance,**

```
<div id="container">
   <ul >
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qV8kv/)**

**[READ MORE FOR `&nbsp;`](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/nbsp.html)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain to me why this happens? Where that gap comes from when I have no content inside `<li>`?

Comment: "You have no content inside" has to be declared by `&nbsp;` to ensure for the browsers that there is no content. - @kikou

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a "bug" (I don't think). It's just the way setting elements on a line works.
You want spaces between words that you type to be spaces right? The spaces
between these blocks are just like spaces between words. That's not to say the
spec couldn't be updated to say that spaces between inline-block elements should
be nothing, but I'm fairly certain that is a huge can of worms that is unlikely to ever
happen.

I use the negative margin and it works for me:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Comment: It's the space *under* the `<li>`s that the OP is asking about, not between them. There is no space between them in the mark-up so that is not an issue in this instance.